# Display the data if "quantity" is not = 0. Using multi map

Tags: visualforce, map, rendered, repeat, outputtext

```
<apex:repeat value="{!prod_quantity_1}" var="key">
    <apex:repeat value="{!prod_quantity_1[key]}" var="innerKey">
        <apex:repeat value="{!prod_quantity_1[key][innerKey]}" var="item">
            <div class="ticket-row">
                <div class="col-xs-8 "> 
                    <h4>{!item.ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c}</h4>
                    <p class="ticket-description">Upclose access to our guest speakers on the backstage.</p>
                    <p style="color:#b3b9bd" class="fee">Fee</p>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <h4 class="price">{!item.Price__c}</h4>
                    <p class="ticket-quantity">x {!innerKey} Ticket (s)</p>
                    <p style="color:#b3b9bd;margin-top:24px" class="fee"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

How can I use the output text render on this? I'm using multi repeat.. If `{!innerKey}` is equal to 0. The product/ticket will not be displayed.

[image]

This is the map declaration:

```
public PageReference BookerInformation(){

        PageReference gotosetup = new PageReference('/apex/bookerinformation?id=' + eventId);
        List<ProntoEvents_Product__c> products_1 = [SELECT Id, Name, ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c, Price__c, Minimum_Quantity__c,Maximum_Quantity__c FROM ProntoEvents_Product__c Where Event_Name__c = :eventId];
        prod_quantity_1 = new Map<ID, Map<String, List<ProntoEvents_Product__c>>>();  
        for (ProntoEvents_Product__c data_prod : products_1){
            Map<String, List<ProntoEvents_Product__c>> prod_object = new Map<String, List<ProntoEvents_Product__c>>();
            prod_object.put( ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(data_prod.ID), new List<ProntoEvents_Product__c>{data_prod});
            prod_quantity_1.put(data_prod.ID, prod_object);

        }

        system.Debug(prod_quantity_1);
        gotosetup.setRedirect(false);
        return gotosetup;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating the question with the map declaration, I can see that your `innerKey` represents a list, so you need to check it's size and use the `rendered` attribute:

`<apex:repeat value="{!prod_quantity_1[key]}" rendered="{!prod_quantity_1[key] != null && prod_quantity_1[key].size != 0}" var="innerKey">`

**Note:** Keep in mind that you might not always have a List value for each key in your map, so you need to check for null values too.

Comment: it still display the Tickets with 0 quantity..

Comment: Can you post your map declarations?

Comment: already added the map declaration.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: hi sir how come it have error..

Comment: Map key size not found in map
Error is in expression '{!prod_quantity_1[key].size != 0}' in component <apex:repeat> in page bookerinformation

Comment: Updated again. You should be able tackle any other issues by researching and reading up. If you have any other questions, please post them as a separate questions and try to avoid lengthy conversations on a thread.

Comment: I get it the and I got the idea from your comments.. <apex:repeat value="{!prod_quantity_1[key][innerKey]}" rendered="{!innerKey != 0}" var="item">